# Prevent Google Image Search hotlink using Nginx rewrite

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, hotlinking

Google Image Search has the ability to point to the original image without displaying the website that is hosting that image. So I want to redirect those requests to a custom page within my site.

Basically, I want to rewrite the following type of URLs (referred from Google):

```
www.website.com/folder1/folder2/year/month/day/ID/string.jpg
```

and redirect them to:

```
www.website.com/ID/page.html
```

where "ID" is a number.

I've tried the following code:

```
set $button_redirect 0;
if ($http_referer ~ "\.google\.") { set $button_redirect 1; }
if ($http_referer ~ "\.google\.[^/]+/blank\.html") { set $button_redirect 0; } 
if ($http_user_agent ~ "Googlebot|bingbot|Slurp|Baiduspider|Yandex|Sogou") { set $button_redirect 0; }
if ($button_redirect = 1) {

    rewrite ^(.*)/folder1/folder2/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$ /index.php?/$5/page.html last;

}
```

However, when I restart the Nginx web server, not a single page can be loaded, which makes me think that I have made a mistake. Can you help me? I'm running Nginx, and I'm using Codeigniter framework.

I took most of the code from here: http://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/hotlinking-protection-and-watermarking-for-google-32/.

Comment: You have tagged your question with "nginx" but you do not refer to nginx within your question.

Comment: You're right, probably I should highlight it better. Anyway I'm talking about this redirect under Nginx web server.

Comment: I see.  For clarity, you can modify your question as follows: "However, when I restart the **nginx** web server..."

Comment: I've just edit it, thanks for the suggestions.